# How do I structure links on my page to access different sub directories?

Tags: php, navigation

I know how to do just about everything I need, the problem I'm running into is the sub directories.

For example:
Nav.php is in the root directory. 
`Index.php` is also in the root directory. 
Now I want to go to a page about cats, located at `about/cats.php`.

When I want to go from `about/cats.php` to `blog/kittens.php` how would I structure the links?

`<a href="about/cats.php">cats</a>` would take me to about/cats just fine from the root directory. But if I'm on the `blog/kittens.php` page, I'd get a link like `about/blog/kittens.php`.

It's not something that needs massive/dynamic arrays or anything, I've just had a hard time wrapping my head around the cleanest way to do this.

How can I keep one navigation file but still have correct links even if I'm 2 or 4 levels from the root? I've seen others use sql databases (if that's the best way I don't mind), but I feel like that's too complicated and I'm just missing a much easier method.

Answer (score 3):

If you add / (Slash) in starting of href it would be considered from root. For example if you are in cats.php page and want to have access to your blog/kitten page so make href like this.

`<a href="/blog/kittens.php">Kittens</a>`

Answer (score 0):

the way to go about is have `navbar/sidebar` with `absolute urls`, so that it can be used any where on your site along with index page.

menu can have links like

```
<a href="/blog/kittens.php">Kittens</a>
<a href="/about/cats.php">Cats</a>
```

hope it helps :)